# What is the Sql Server equivalent for Oracle's DBMS_ASSERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-injection

**DBMS_ASSERT** is one of the keys to prevent SQL injection attacks in Oracle. I tried a cursory search...is there any SQL Server 2005/2008 equivalent for this functionality?

I am looking for a specific implementation that has a counterpart of all the respective Oracle package members of DBMS_ASSERT.

- NOOP
- SIMPLE_SQL_NAME
- QUALIFIED_SQL_NAME
- SCHEMA_NAME

I know the best-practices of preventing injection...bind variables...being one of them.
But,in this question I am specifically looking for a good way to sanitize input...in scenarios where bind-variables were not used.

Do you have any specific implemetations?
Is there a library that actually is a SQL Server Port of the Oracle package?

Comment: Using bind variables is by far much better than using DBMS_ASSERT or any similar method of sanitizing user input.

Comment: For those of us who know SQL Server but not Oracle, what does DBMS_ASSERT do, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only likely option you have is `QUOTENAME` which is used to escape object names (and thus may be an equivalent for `SIMPLE_SQL_NAME` or `ENQUOTE_NAME` and possibly others. So table names (providing they are not qualified with owner or database) and column names can be escaped.

There isn't a mechanism for fully qualifying an object (e.g., turning table 'bob' into 'database.owner.bob'), so you'd have to put this together manually, optionally using `QUOTENAME` to escape the values, e.g.:

`QUOTENAME(@database) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@owner) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tableName)`

If the object is in the existing database, then you could use DB_NAME(), and assume that the owner's going to be passed in as a variable:

`DB_NAME() + '.' + QUOTENAME(@owner) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@tablename)`

In a really convoluted way, you can get owner out as well:

`USER_NAME(OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(@tablename), 'ownerid')))`

Yes I realise all of these may be considered workarounds, but they are options.

However for escaping values you really are on your own: there is no built-in SQL Server equivalent, so would be all manual string manipulation. You might be able to create a UDF to sit in place to do this, although if you're going to that effort, it's probably also worth looking at rewriting the sproc using SQL Server sp_ExecuteSQL semantics.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do dynamic queries by building strings and the EXECuting them.

Use `sp_executesql` and pass parameters as parameters.

You'll find that sql injection is no more.

**EDIT**: sorry, I was in a hurry and wrote the wrong command. it's not sp_execute, it's sp_executesql; it takes a string and a set of parameters: all the encoding and escaping of the parameters is done by SQL Server.

**EDIT2**: [sp_executesql statement explaination](http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/sp_ea-ez_4.htm)

Comment: @Patonza This answer doesn't serve any value...I am looking for Oracle equivalents not ways to prevent injection. Please read my question and be topical and specific

Comment: Ok, sorry, I guess you are porting some software from Oracle to MS SQL Server. In that scenario you for sure need a 1:1 replacement for DBMS_ASSERT. But when possible (eg. new code) it's better to avoid the problem altogether. I thought someone could profit from my advice, maybe I should have posted a comment instead of an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I have is [TSQLAssert for TSQLMacro](http://www.datamanipulation.net/tsqlmacro/tsqlassert.asp) but it only supports TSQL Stored Procedures. It's free.

> TSQLAssert is an assertion framework
>   built on top of TSQLMacro. It is
>   intended to provide debug-time
>   assertion failures similar to
>   assertions in languages like C++ --
>   with an additional logging component
>   not found in those languages.
>   TSQLAssert can be used only within
>   stored procedures and triggers --
>   unfortunately, user-defined functions
>   and views do not support many of the
>   keywords that allow it to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no magic "prevent injection" command.  The methodology is a combination of:

1. Using parameterized queries to ensure type safety
2. Sanitize inputs before passing them to the database layer
3. When you can't do 1. and 2., replace ' with '' in all input, and other sanitize methods before blindly executing dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Aaron I am aware of the methodologies...my question is specific to DBMS_ASSERT equivalency. If an exact equivalent doesn't exist some of the DB experts may have a library/extensio written ... to emulate it. I am looking forward to hear on those lines

Comment: I don't know of any, sorry.  I'm sure any extensions people have written have been for the front-end / middle tier, not at the database level.

Answer (score 1):

As such there is no equivalent of DBMS_ASSERT in SQL SERVER.

However enhancing the answer of Aaron Bertrand by this link
[SQL Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I also was once looking for something similar to `DBMS_ASSERT` for Sql Server, but to no avail.
So I ended up writing a collection of PROCs that we needed.

Microsoft should really ship something similar, but till then, you're on your own.